# sql get booking clashes between two times

Tags: mysql, oop

I have a sql booking question.  The table has idstylist, bdate, stime and etime.

Basically the stylist can only do one job at a time.  So when placing a booking I need to check that that stylist is not already busy on another booking.  Here is my clash method;

```
public function checkClash($bdate, $stime,$stylist){
    $query = sprintf("SELECT id FROM table WHERE (date=%s AND idstylist=%s) AND (%s BETWEEN stime AND etime)",

        $this->db->GetSQLValueString($bdate, "date"),
        $this->db->GetSQLValueString($stylist, "int"),
        $this->db->GetSQLValueString($stime, "text"));
        $result = $this->db->query($query);
         if($result  && $this->db->num_rows($result) > 0){
                return true;

        }
        return false;   

}
```

As far as I understand my query is selecting all bookings from (date) where idstylist is this and the start time is >= $stime but <=$stime.

So for example I have a row in the database that looks like this;

id   |  date          |  idstylist |  stime      |     etime

1  |   2014-12-05     |   68       |    07:00:00  |    07:30:00

Now Im trying to place a booking for the same stylist at 07:10:00 on the same date which should fail but the system is allowing me to make this booking.  I cant see whats wrong with my query.

```
   //next check for clashes in the booking table
    $clash = $bookings->checkClash($_POST['bdate'],$_POST['stime'], $_POST['stylist']);
    if($clash==true){
        $errors[] = "Booking clashes.  Please try again";   
    }
```

Comment: Please stop using sprintf to create sql queries. Use parameterized queries, because Bobby Tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is turning into a debugging session.

From your SQL: (stime>=%s AND etime<=%s)

Replace with values: ('7:00' >= '7:10' AND '7:30' <= '7:10')

I gues you want: (%s BETWEEN stime and etime)

Comment: that went through fine and allowed another booking

Comment: I changed my query to match what you wrote below and now it works fine thank you very much.  Ill update the code above to what works